# KeyPoints opencv FAST detector android

Tags: java, android, performance, opencv

I'm trying to use Opencv FAST detector setting a threshold in Android. I found a similar solved problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537280/keypoint-list-to-matofkeypoint). I have listed the keypoints list after detect method as suggested, but still doesn't work for me. In my case I want to detect the key points on my camera frame:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    Mat mat=inputFrame.rgba();
    FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
    fast.detect(mat, points);

    // Sort and select 500 best keypoints
    List<KeyPoint> listOfKeypoints = points.toList();
    Collections.sort(listOfKeypoints, new Comparator<KeyPoint>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(KeyPoint kp1, KeyPoint kp2) {
            // Sort them in descending order, so the best response KPs will come first
            return (int) (kp2.response - kp1.response);
        }
    });
    List<KeyPoint> listOfBestKeypoints = listOfKeypoints.subList(0, 500);
    points.fromList(listOfBestKeypoints);   



    Scalar redcolor = new Scalar(255,0,0);
    Mat mRgba= mat.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4);

    Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, points, mRgba, redcolor, 3);

    return mRgba;
}
```

Problem is that my listOfKeypoints remains null. If I don't try to set the threshold the code works fine  but too slow.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my list is null only the first time onCameraFrame is called. So I can make it works using a class variable and populating my list starting from the second call.

```
private int count=0;
```

And then in onCameraFrame;

```
if (count!=0) {
        //Sort and select 500 best keypoints
        List<KeyPoint> listOfKeypoints =  points.toList();
        Collections.sort(listOfKeypoints, new Comparator<KeyPoint>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(KeyPoint kp1, KeyPoint kp2) {
                // Sort them in descending order, so the best response KPs will come first
                return (int) (kp2.response - kp1.response);
            }
        });
        List<KeyPoint> listOfBestKeypoints = listOfKeypoints.subList(0, 500);
        points.fromList(listOfBestKeypoints);

    } 
    count++;
```

In this way it works, but I still don't understand why on the first call of onCameraFrame the list is null. Any ideas?